# Receive push is not working after I enable push notifications from settings (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

Hi I had run in to the next issue on iOS 9.3.2, steps to reproduce:

1. I open the app which successfuly register for push notifications; at this point receive push is working as a charm.
2. put the app in background go to settings disable push notification open the app again at this point I don't receive any push as expected.
3. put the app in background go to settings enable push notification open the app at this point I don't receive any push only if I close the app at all then opend again.

Can some one help me on this issue?

I make register for push notifications in the next way:
In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions just before return I call next lines of code:

```
 UIUserNotificationType userNotificationType = (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationType categories:nil]];
```

Then in app delegate I had listen to the next delegates methods:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // send device token to my server
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // show error alert
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(nonnull UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [app registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
   // treat receive push notification
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler {
    // treat receive push notification
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code here? I suspect there is a missing call in your AppDelegate

Comment: @bplattenburg I had added the code in the description.